# How come I can just "Import Image"?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In python, I can type `import Image` to import the Python Imaging Library (PIL). I can just type that instead of `from PIL import Image`, like everyone else seems to do. How come I can do this? Is there any difference between `from PIL import Image` and `import Image`?

Should I assume that other people can't do this? (That is, when writing code to distribute to others.)

I use Python 2.7.4. Here's an example of code that runs perfectly for me in the REPL:

```
> import Image
> x = Image.new("RGB",(32,32),"blue)
> x.save("test.png","PNG")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when you "import Image" directly, what is really going on inside that Image module is: "from PIL.Image import *", which copies all of the names from the PIL.Image module into the Image module.

Take a look at the source:

```
In [1]: import Image

In [2]: Image??
Type:        module
String form: <module 'Image' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat/Image.pyc'>
File:        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat/Image.py
Source:      from PIL.Image import *
```

Comment: Yup! A result from the REPL was similar: 
`>>> Image  
<module 'Image' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat/Image.pyc'>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use import in several different ways.

Here is a [nice article on the common variations of import](http://blog.amir.rachum.com/blog/2013/10/10/python-importing/) (you can do even do this in other ways too)